# Command line get path to gem

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I found [**this question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5226707/how-to-find-the-path-a-ruby-gem-is-installed-at-i-e-gem-lib-path-c-f-gem-bin), but he specifially says **no** command line. Well I do want command line. I see I can run

```
$ gem which jekyll
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/jekyll-0.12.0/lib/jekyll.rb
```

However I would prefer something like

```
$ foo jekyll
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/jekyll-0.12.0
```

where `foo` is the mystery command. I can parse `gem which` if needed, but prefer something more elegant. Note, `bundle` is out of the question.

Comment: `alias foo='gem which'`

Answer (score 10):

If you are using Bundler, `bundle show <gem name>` does what you're after. I'll look into non-Bundler.

Answer (score 1):

Since `gem` is simply a ruby script wrapper around `Gem::GemRunner` and you want to gain a functionality not implemented within default set of commands, I would suggest you to create your own [Gem::Command](http://rubygems.rubyforge.org/rubygems-update/Gem/Command.html).

It’s really straightforward, plus you may implement as many additional functionality as you want.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

It useful to get a location of the library file with:

```
$ gem which "gemname"
```