# Using Twitter Bootstrap for SASS without Rails or Compass

Tags: ruby, twitter-bootstrap, sass

I'm trying to use [Twitter Bootstrap for SASS](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass), but at the moment it's not integrated into a Rails project, and I don't I need the stuff I'd get from [Compass](http://compass-style.org/). I (think I) want a Ruby script that will generate my CSS, JS and Font files and put them in the right places, but having spent a couple of hours going round in circles with the docs, I can't figure this out.

I have a directory like:

```
site/
  css/
    bootstrap_variables.scss
    application.scss
    site.scss
  fonts/
  index.html
  js/
```

`css/bootstrap_variables.scss` contains my custom variations on Bootstrap's default variables.

`css/site.scss` contains the site-specific, non-Bootstrap, CSS.

`css/application.scss` looks something like this:

```
@import "bootstrap_variables.scss";

// Import Bootstrap modules I need, but not others.
@import "bootstrap/variables";
@import "bootstrap/mixins";
// ... etc

@import "site.scss"
```

I've installed the `bootstrap-sass` gem. And now I want a script that does:

1. Process `css/application.scss` with SASS and outputs `css/application.css`.
2. Put the Bootstrap JavaScript I need into a single file in `js/`. (How do I specify which JS modules I need?)
3. If I'm using Bootstrap's icons, put the glyphicons fonts in `fonts/`.

If this sounds like madness, and I'm going about this entirely wrong, feel free to tell me that too!

Comment: Sorry for this useless comment, but is `CSS` tag necessary for this question?

Comment: You need a sass compiler, what's wrong with compass?

Comment: @HashemQolami You're right, yes - I guess my head was stuck in CSS, but it's not relevant here.

Comment: @SergioAristizábal Maybe I've misunderstood, but SASS doesn't require Compass - [it can generate compiled CSS by itself](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#using_sass).

Comment: "I (think I) want a Ruby script that will generate my CSS, JS and Font files and put them in the right places", so in other words, you want Compass?

Comment: I didn't think so -- from its site I thought it was mostly lots of things to make writing SASS/CSS easier. But maybe it's the simplest way to generate SASS files? I can't see anything in the docs about JavaScript, fonts etc -- have I missed them?

Comment: I've spent some time with Compass and have it generating custom Bootstrap CSS using the `bootstrap-sass` gem. But can't see how to get it dealing with its JS or fonts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> And now I want a script that does:

I'm not sure why you need this script at all. Cause if you can run the script you also can install sass and run `sass css/application.scss css/application.css`. You can install all bootstrap's file in your `site` folder by running `bower install bootstrap-sass` and then run the `sass` command with `--load-path` option which should point to your `bower_components` folder. You can also copy / or link the required javascripts and font from the `bower_components` folder.

Or consider to use Gulp or Grunt to set up your build chain.

But you can use Sass programmatically indeed.

> Process css/application.scss with SASS and outputs css/application.css.

Your script.rb should look something like that shown below:

```
/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'sass'
require 'bootstrap-sass'

sass_engine = Sass::Engine.for_file('css/application.scss',{
  :style => :compact,
  :syntax => :scss
})

output = sass_engine.render

File.open("css/application.css", 'w+') {|f| f.write(output) }
```

Notice that you also should have to integrate the autoprefixer.

> Put the Bootstrap JavaScript I need into a single file in js/

After installing the bootstrap-sass gem you can read the javascript files from the gem (see: [How to find the path a Ruby Gem is installed at (i.e. Gem.lib_path c.f. Gem.bin_path)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5226707/how-to-find-the-path-a-ruby-gem-is-installed-at-i-e-gem-lib-path-c-f-gem-bin)).

So the get the content of the affix plugin you can use:

```
file = File.new(Gem::Specification.find_by_name("bootstrap-sass").gem_dir + "/assets/javascripts/bootstrap/affix.js", "r")
```

You you can read the required script, concatenate their content, minify and copy

> If I'm using Bootstrap's icons, put the glyphicons fonts in fonts/.

As above, copy them from `Gem::Specification.find_by_name("bootstrap-sass").gem_dir + "/assets/fonts`

Comment: This question was some time ago and I'd do things differently now (Gulp or Grunt, as you suggest). But I'll mark this correct as it sounds like it answers my question of the time. Thanks!